# How to pass headers while using networked aframe?

Tags: javascript, aframe, aframe-networked

While using Networked Aframe, we set up the client side as follows:

```
<a-scene networked-scene="
  serverURL: /;
  app: <appId>;
  room: <roomName>;
  connectOnLoad: true;
  onConnect: onConnect;
  adapter: wseasyrtc;
  audio: false;
  video: false;
  debug: false;
">
  ...
</a-scene>
```

I wish to pass header info, specifically auth headers so that I can use them on the server side. How do I pass header info? I saw something like the below for firebase:

```
<script>
    window.firebaseConfig = {
      authType: 'none',
      apiKey: 'your-api-key',
      authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: "your-projectId",
      storageBucket: "your-storageBucket",
      messagingSenderId: "your-messagingSenderId",
      appId: "your-appId",
      measurementId: "your-measurementId"
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Set adapter to firebase -->
   <a-scene networked-scene="
        adapter: firebase;
    ">
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Do we have an equivalent of this for easyrtc adapter?

Comment: Same problem, did you find solution?